# Firebase Rules and flutter : How to check for username availability

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Hello I am working with Firestore and flutter. I need to check the username availability when someone creates a new account.
I want to make that when the user is not connected in the app, the field 'username' of the collection "User Data" can be access with get().
However, the code in rules return several errors of 'expected {' but even if I add the '{', it stills does not accept it.

The code in rule that doesn't work and firebase won't allow me to install this rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match /User Data/{User Data} {

        allow read: true;

    }

}
```

What I've tried so far :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match /User Data/{User Data} {

        allow read: request.resource.data == resource.data.username;
    }

}
```

The code in flutter :

```
Future<bool> checkUsernameAvailability(String val) async {
    final result = await Firestore.instance.collection("User Data").where('username', isEqualTo: val).getDocuments();

    return result.documents.isEmpty;
  }
```

```
onPressed: () async {
                              final valid = await checkUsernameAvailability(_usernameController.text);
                              if (!valid) {
                                error = AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                    .translate('this_username_is_not_available');
                              } else if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                setState(() => loading = true);
                                dynamic result =
                                    await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(
                                        _emailController.text,
                                        _passwordController.text,
                                        _nameController.text,
                                    _usernameController.text);
                                if (result == null) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    loading = false;
                                    error = AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                        .translate('please_enter_email');
                                  });
                                }
                              }
                            }
```

All help is welcomed thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can seperately write security rules for all collections. When you use `match /{document=**}` expression to allow read and write for authenticated users, it overrides other rules.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /User Data/{User Data} {
        allow read: request.resource.data == resource.data.username
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
}
```